# Spring Multiple Entry Point for REST and Web

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-data

I try to implement my app with Spring Security.

I need to create a web application and a REST API but I need to have an authentication system.
I'm using Spring Security 3.2 with Spring 4.0

This is a scenario with web app (browser):

1. User go to login page and enter information
2. User click on login
3. System redirect user to the home page

...and this is the scenario with REST (Spring RestTemplate):

1. User login with user and password
2. System create a token and save association in DB and add token to header
3. User request something by rest
4. System get token in header
5. System check availibility of token
6. System execute the request and return result

Actually my problem is how to implement the choice between REST and browser request?

I don't understand. Do you have an example?

Answer (score 0):

not sure i understand your "REST" flow - why do you mention REST vs web? they both the same thing. you can write a web-app that has RESTfull API.

The login page is a way for web-apps to get user authenticated and authorized, and get the access toke.

Comment: If I understand correctly, REST is only Stateless. Web can use statefull connection.

Comment: as i said - you can write a web-app, that exposes REST API. each time a client wants to use the REST API, it will pass the token in the header. this is how it works...

Answer (score 0):

You could use Spring Security to have your login page, once the `jsessionid` is created you can use that session in the REST service and let Spring Security to allow access to it.

Comment: Yes but from a mobile app how to connect without a webpage but directly via rest and get session id? I don't find/understand. I tried to find example on web but all are about rest app only (api) or web only never both. I tried myself by using a custom filter but the command doFilter does not continue the filterchain. I'm lost.

Comment: I found this article yesterday it could help http://blog.safaribooksonline.com/2013/10/08/secure-rest-services-with-spring-security/